# Best way to use my own module in my python project

Tags: python, git, python-module

I can't find an answer for this question. Probably because I have not the good keywords. If this is too basic, please just tell me where to look for.

We have a Python project *our_project* in which I want to use a little Python module that I wrote : *my_module* .

*our_project* and *my_module* both have a git repo. I do not want to just put `my_module.py` into `our_project/` because I want to keep improving  *my_module* independently of *our_project*  and be abble to use it in other projects.

I'm looking for a simple way to acces the most rencent version of *my_module* from *our_project*. (for me and my collaborators)

What should I do ?

Comment: If it's just one file, I'd say that a symlink to another repo + putting it to the ignore file may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a library on another repo with its own [setuptools configuration](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide).

You can use [pip's editable install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#id44) to install it and also keep it updated while being develop. It allows you to install dependencies directly from git repositories.